# Convert paging logic from SQL to Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am totally new to Linq.
I need to convert paging logic from SQL to Linq.
My paging logic in SQL is:

```
where num BETWEEN ((@pageNumber-1)*@pageSize) + 1 and (@pageSize * @pageNumber)
```

So, if `pageNumber` is `2` and `pageSize` is `30`, my query will pull records from row `31` up-to row `60`.

I implemented same logic in LINQ, but it pulls wrong no of records:

```
query.Skip(pageNumber - 1).Take(pageSize * pageNumber).AsQueryable();
```

Can someone please, tell me what is wrong in my LINQ query.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to multiply what you skip by the page size, the same way as in SQL, and take the desired rows next. 
So for you it would be like:

```
query.Skip((pageNumber - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to Skip  and Take records rather than whole pages in Linq:

```
query.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
query.Skip((pageNumber - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize).AsQueryable();
```

`Skip`->skipping number of records, `Take` is taking  number of records after the skipped one.So if you want to show 31 to 60. You need to `Skip` 30 and `Take` 30.

In the future you can call:

```
query.Skip((pageNumber - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToString();
```

With this you can see what `Sql` this `LINQ` will produce